# Best way to Install Pip packages(Ubuntu/Linux)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip

I was wondering since there are so many optinos to install a python package which one is be best and most convenient. should I install packages with `sudo` and `pip3` commands,
E.g

```
sudo pip3 install <package>
```

only using `pip3`
E.g

```
pip3 install <package>
```

or using apt

```
sudo apt install <python-package>
```

I was wondering which is the go-to and will be most convenient in the future. Mostly wondering what is the difference between `Sudo pip3` and `pip3` what difference does it make and which one I should use.

Comment: Note that I have suggested to close this question, since it can lead to opinion-based answers (my answer already is). Ten people may provide you with 10 different answers, including more advanced suggestions about virtual environments and beyond.

Comment: @9769953 Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]

Comment: @Rob I did, because I feel there's also (good) advice in it. I don't really care otherwise; SO has a bunch of rules which are continuously treaded, so a bit of flexibility works fine.

Comment: @9769953 At one time, years ago, one would never get away with it. Nowadays, seems like anything goes and I've all but given up.

Comment: Tony the pony still got away with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `sudo` with `pip`. There is a chance you'll overwrite system-installed packages, and mess up your OS.

`sudo apt install <python-package>` is pretty safe, but may result in outdated packages, and will definitely not include all packages you may want to install.

`pip3 install <package>` will install packages for just the current user (thus, not system-wide; if you're the only user, you're fine), and is what I would recommend.

Going further, virtual environment or use of Conda (an "extended" virtual environment manager) are potentially even safer, at the cost of a little more work to set up, and a bit more disk space (usually, the latter is insignificant).

You will have to read up on the use of virtual environment or Conda. That topic is too long for a standard answer here.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest as first step reading package documentation, as it often contains information regarding how to install it. Few examples regarding popular packages

- [`click`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/quickstart/) suggests `pip install click`
- [`jinja2`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/intro/#installation) suggests `pip install Jinja2`
- [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/install/) suggests `python -m pip install requests`

Before that check to what version pertains `python` in your machine (by checking output of `python --version`), if it is Python 2 and you want to install packages to Python 3, then you need to use `pip3` and `python3` rather than `pip` and `python`, if it is Python 3 you might use command as they are.

Comment: These example installation steps all amount to the same (on a normally configured system). Also, the OP already mentions `pip3`, and using Python 2/pip2 should basically be banned (as that indicates the package is not supported anymore, and hasn't been for a while).

Comment: I don't think it actually answers the question the OP is asking. For example, NumPy suggests to use Conda, or pip. But there often are also python-numpy packages for the OS itself. What then to use?